# Systemtap probe kernel module function while that module is loaded

Tags: kernel-modules, debugging, tracing, systemtap

How to use a Systemtap probe on a kernel module function while that module is loaded. I am trying to print the functions being called for a particular module while it is being loaded. Suppose I have a kernel module `hello.ko` which is not loaded. Now I want to trace a function `hello_init()` of that module. I tried with the following Systemtap script but it did not work.

Command:

`stap test10.stp -c "modprobe hello"` --> this printed nothing

Systemtap script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stap

global traces

probe module("hello").function("hello_init") {
    printf("hello")
    print_stack(backtrace())
}
```

Kernel module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>       
#include <linux/kernel.h>       
#include <linux/init.h>         
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world\n");
return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Done\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could see `staprun` sends only `kallsyms_on_each_symbol` in `int send_relocation_kernel()` in `staprun.c` to the generated kernel module, which in turn does not set the kprobe address in the kernel module because `kallsyms_on_each_symbol` does not find the probe symbol in the kernel module. For a quick "test" one could send the address of `module_kallsyms_on_each_symbol` in place of `kallsyms_on_each_symbol` in `int send_relocation_kernel()` it works since both functions have the same signature.

replace

```
else if (linesize - pos == sizeof "kallsyms_on_each_symbol"
        && !strcmp(line + pos, "kallsyms_on_each_symbol" "\n"))
  {
     rc = send_a_relocation ("kernel", "kallsyms_on_each_symbol", address);
```

with

```
else if (linesize - pos == sizeof "module_kallsyms_on_each_symbol"
        && !strcmp(line + pos, "module_kallsyms_on_each_symbol" "\n"))
  {
     rc = send_a_relocation ("kernel", "kallsyms_on_each_symbol", address);
```

With this change the probe in the `init()` function should print something.